# Most pythonic way to store all readonly properties of a class in a list

Tags: python

I have a lot of properties, and

```
class ClassA:
    @property
    def func1(self):
        self.__string1 = "a"
        return self.__string1

    @property
    def func2(self):
        self.__string2 = "b"
        return self.__string2

    def func3(self):
        self.__list = [self.func1, self.func2]
```

seems redundant, especially when there are a lot of properties of a class. Is there a more compact way of doing this without having to list every single property?

Comment: Why do you want to store them?

Comment: I need to store whether they are None or not, and I need to do itertools.compress() on them with another list to get a total number

Comment: Maybe `self.__dict__.keys()` assuming you have an obj.

Comment: @monk but this will include all instance variables, not just "the readonly properties"

Comment: why don't you use `tuple`? it's like an array and immutable. but I never tried it like in your case so you can judge me

Comment: Why are you setting an instance variable and then returning it?  I feel like this is an X/Y problem

Comment: It's just an example of what my actual code looks like. It's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `__dict__` attribute and combine it with the `isinstance`
method to filter out non property attributes:

```py
> python
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     not_a_property = None
...     @property
...     def func1():
...         return "string1"
...     @property
...     def func2():
...         return "string2"
...
>>> [p for p,v in A.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, property)] 
['func1', 'func2']
>>>
```

Comment: I don't want to get all attributes, I want to get all properties. By read only, I just mean it has no setter method.

Comment: In my experience, there is rarely a real need to use `__dict__` (it is a kind of a hack anyway). I've used it maybe three times in 10 years of writing Python code. My hunch is that the OP is trying to solve the wrong problem. Maybe showing more code would help.

Comment: I updated it to show what I mean in more detail if that helps.

Comment: well then use the `isinstance` built in to check whether your attribute is a property

Comment: Can you show example code of what you mean based off the updated code of mine?

Comment: @RkMpNY5Y I have updated the code, can you try it out?

Comment: This just gets the names of the functions, I want the values the functions return.

Comment: `[v for p,v in A.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, property)]` use this then. You could have come up with that yourself too, there is no need to ask over and over again...

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you propose you might want to take a look at [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which allow you to avoid a lot of boiler plate. It also allows you to make it read-only with a simple `frozen` argument. You could store all of your properties in a data class inside your class.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen = True)
class MyPropertyContainer():
    property1: str
    property2: float
    # ...
```

Such a class would allow you to store all your read only properties in a single object which is easily accessible. The only down side is that you would need to access those properties through an additional dot from outside the class: `my_object.my_properties.property1` or you could write properties assessors for each properties if you want to avoid that (which I do not recommend).

Afterwards, you can get all your arguments as a dict. If you need to you can extract a list from that. Provided you defined the data class above, it would look as follow:

```py
my_properties = MyPropertyContainer('aString', 12, ...)  # Instantiate what you want
properties_dict = my_properties.asDict()          # Get the dictionnary
properties_list = list(properties_dict.values())  # Dict to list
```

Based on the example you provided, a solution would be to rewrite your class as follow:

```py
# Make a data class for private properties
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class PropertyContainer():
    func1: str
    func2: str

class A():
    
    # Since we're readonly we set the values on instanciation
    def __init__(self, func1_val, func2_val):
        self.properties = PropertyContainer(func1_val, func2_val)

    # Here we get the values from all readonly
    def func3(self):
         return list(self.properties.asDict().values())

    # You could also have sth like this for retro compatibility
    @property
    def func2(self):
        return self.properties.func1
```

Comment: This seems something very useful to implement, but I can't wrap my head around how to even implement it. The thing is, I have unknown values that I want to assign to a dataclass, and all of these values are returned by @property methods in an already existing class. Could you give a sample as to what this would look like?

Comment: Mmm... I see... so you basically want to inherit from an existing class and then just sort through private properties instead of rewriting the class? If that's the case, data class is not for you. It would require to rewrite the original class to put all of your read-only param in it (which probably belong in a class together since you want to access them all). If you don't want to rewrite the class then you have to play around with the __dict__ method and dataclasses won't be of any use.

Comment: The read-only parameters are all in the same class, could you provide a sample of how to pass these all to a dataclass?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do so easily. The question wasn't clear to me. What I was suggesting was to rewrite the class that contains your readonly parameters. If that's what you want do I'll gladly provide you with an example. If not then I suggest you look for something along the line what @NoBlockhit suggests

Comment: Could you provide that example? It might be useful with what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Alright... here is an example... note that since we're having readonly variables, we have to set them at the instanciation. If you want to change them later you can use setaattr but I wouldn't recommand it. Overall if that does what you want I would maybe question the whole implementation of your class... could a tuple, namedtuple, numpy array or panda array acomplish what you want, simpler and better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244296/discussion-between-rkmpny5y-and-lniederha).